# wav stopped working with AudioServices on my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, audio

I have a wav file that was working fine. It is played using the AudioServices methods. Suddenly it stopped working. The weird thing is if i change he wav file to a different one that works. Any idea what is going on? The non working sound is slightly longer (still <10seconds) but it was originally working so I just can't figure it out.

Any suggestions of what to try would be most appreciated. Thanks :-)

Comment: I don't have access to my code right now, but all I am doing to stop the sound from working is changing the name of the wav file for another in the library, surely this isn't a code issue?!

Comment: If it isn't a code issue, then this is the wrong site to ask the question.

Comment: I don't agree that this is not programming related. Most of a programmer's time is spent troubleshooting these things, and you can't tell the customer "it's not my fault, it just stopped working". Voting to reopen.

Comment: @erikkallen: Okay, I'm reopening.  My one vote to close shouldn't be more powerful than your one to open.  The rest of the community can decide if it stays.

Answer (score 0):

AudioServices won't play sounds longer than 5 seconds.  Playing longer sounds will require using a different Audio approach.

Here's a decent example of playing sounds with another method:
http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/tutorial/how-to-play-audio-with-the-iphone-sdk